# Variance of random variables

Tags: random-variables

Dear friends  I am Bernardo
I am trying to derive the variance of an estimator, but I need help in some concepts. I will relate to a very simple way:
suppose that we have three random variables: $X, Y, Z$
2 cases:
case 1: $X,Y$ dependents  and $Z$ independent of both.
case 2: all dependents

I want the variance of  $X+Y\cdot Z$

I will greatly appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance
Bernardo

Answer (score 1):

**Hint for case $1)$** : Recall that $\mathrm{V}[X]$ can be rewritten as

$\mathrm{V}[X]=\mathrm{E}[X^2]+(\mathrm{E}[X])^2$

And that if two random variables $X$ and $Y$are independent, then:

$\mathrm{E}[XY]=\mathrm{E}[X]\mathrm{E}[Y]$

Using the linearity of the expectation operator, that is:

$\mathrm{E}[\alpha X+\beta Y]=\alpha \mathrm{E}[X]+\beta \mathrm{E}[Y]$

you should be able to continue from that.